# imagePicker won't open after allowing access to photo and camera

Tags: android, react-native

I've checked all the documents and threads and can't seem to find any solution to this. I've read threads with similar issues but when trying to apply their solutions I can't seem to get it working.

I'm trying to enable uploading photo/video from storage/camera to my app. When opening the RN imagePicker to begin the upload, the "Allow"-alert comes up: "Allow myApp to access photos, media and files on your device?".

**The problem is** that after allowing access the ImagePicker won't move on with its' process - the "Allow"-question dissapears and the app behaves as if nothing has happend. When trying to open the imagePicker again, the same process repeats itself, despite the fact that when running Permissions.openSettings() (opening the apps permission settings) i can note that the permissions has been changed in accordance with the choice made from the "Allow"-question. In other words, moment 22.

Im running Nexus 5, Android 6.0 with targetSdkVersion **23** on a Genymotion emulator.

Anyone who've had the exact same issue and solved it?
Don't think I've let any important information out, but please let me know if that's the case.

```
 // **Permission results in the MainActivity.java-file.**
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
    switch(permsRequestCode){
        case PERMISSION_REQ_CODE:
            // example how to get result of permissions requests (there can be more then one permission dialog)
            // boolean readAccepted = grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            // boolean writeAccepted = grantResults[1]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            // checking permissions to prevent situation when user denied some permission
            checkPerms();
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: **onRequestPermissionResult(int , String[] , int[])** is usually the override in your **activity** where the code flow happens to be when **the "Allow"-question dissapears and the app behaves as if nothing has happened**

Comment: @ShayHaned - I don't know much java-code, but something like the code I added in the description? Thanks for your effort.